# The role of the topology in a topological space.

Tags: general-topology

Consider the topological space $(X, T)$ where $X$ is a set and $T$ is a topology which is a family of open subsets of $X$. I learned that the continuity of a function is determined by the topology. Say, the continuity of a function from $(X,T_{1})$ to $(X,T_{2})$ is determined by the relation between $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ even though its domain and codomain remain the same. $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ are families of the open subsets of $X$ by definition.

My question: Some open sets in $T_{1}$ need not be contained in $T_{2}$ because a set can have different topologies. In that case, are such sets not considered as open sets in $(X,T_{2})$?

Comment: Openness is always relative to the topology, so yes, you can have a set that's open in one topology and not in another topology on the same underlying set. This isn't just some contrived artifact of the theory, either, there are real occasions in which it makes sense to do this.

Comment: @Ian Is it plausible to think that if we assume $(X, T)$ is metrizable, the different topologies on the same set are formed by different metrics?

Comment: Metrizability is the property of the topology. You could have two different metrizable topologies on the same set and these would definitely be induced by different metrics. The same topology can also be induced by many metrics. As a simple example, if $c>0$ and $d$ is a metric then $(x,y) \mapsto cd(x,y)$ is another metric.

Comment: It may help to think a little bit more abstractly: from the point of view of general topology, the only thing that actually means anything about the underlying set of a topological space is its cardinality. So for example $\mathbb{R}$ and $P(\mathbb{N})$ are really "the same". (To the experts: please don't reply to what I just said with axiom-of-choice-related comments...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some confusion when you say that “$T$ is a topology which is a family of open subsets of $X$”. This is true, but the whole truth is that $T$ is *the* family of *all* open subsets of $X$. So, if $T_1\not\subset T_2$, and if $O\in T_1\setminus T_2$, then $O$ is *not* an open subset of $(X,T_2)$.

Comment: Do you mean that $T$ is the family of all open subsets of $X$ 'in that topological space?'

Comment: The set $T$ is the set of all open subsets of the topological space $(X,T)$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is yes, such sets need not be "considered as open in $T_2$. To put it more precisely, there are elements of $T_1$ which are not elements of $T_2$ (recall that elements of $T_1$ and $T_2$ are themselves *subsets* of $X$).

Consider $(\mathbb{R},T_1)$, $(\mathbb{R},T_2)$ and $(\mathbb{R},T_3)$ where $T_1$ is the usual Euclidean topology, $T_2$ is the *discrete* topology, (so every subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is in $T_2$), and $T_3$ is the *coarse* topology (the only elements of $T_3$ are $\mathbb{R}$ and $\emptyset$).

Now, for example, *any* function $f:(\mathbb{R},T_2) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},T_1)$ is continuous. Here there are many elements of $T_2$ which are not contained in $T_1$.

The point here is that the topology is an entirely separate thing from the underlying set. I start with the set $\mathbb{R}$, and this does *not* come with a topology. It is just a set, in the same way that $\{a,b,c\}$ is just a set (despite the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is a lot bigger). I must *equip* it with a topology. Once I've done that, I have a topological space. I can create a different topological space, with the same underlying set, by equipping $\mathbb{R}$ with a different topology (and that's what I've done above). Now that I have these two topological spaces, I can start talking about continuous maps from one of them to the other.